# How get informations of antivirus installed on smartphone?

Tags: java, android

I know that on operational system Windows is possible retrieve some informations about the antivirus that is installed on computer through WMI service using this vbscript below:

```
strComputer = "."

Set oWMI = GetObject( _

  "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\SecurityCenter")


Set colItems = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from AntiVirusProduct")


For Each objItem in colItems

  With objItem

    WScript.Echo .companyName

    WScript.Echo .displayName

    WScript.Echo .instanceGuid

    WScript.Echo .onAccessScanningEnabled

    WScript.Echo .pathToSignedProductExe

    WScript.Echo .productHasNotifiedUser

    WScript.Echo .productState

    WScript.Echo .productUptoDate

    WScript.Echo .productWantsWscNotifications

    WScript.Echo .versionNumber

  End With

Next
```

[**Reference**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2008/05/12/how-to-get-antivirus-information-with-wmi-vbscript/)

There something in Java Android able to make the same/similar task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that on operational system Windows is possible retrieve some informations about the antivirus that is installed on computer through WMI service using this vbscript below

Note that your reference for this is a 10-year-old blog post.

> There something in Java Android able to make the same/similar task?

I cannot think of any. There is no requirement for an Android app to advertise its capabilities in this way.